# Javascript - Prototype for 'Set' object

Tags: javascript, prototype

IE 10 does not support 'Set' type but my Javascript uses Set.

What are my options considering changing Set in my code is a costly affair.

Is there possibility of creating a Prototype for it?

If yes is there ready prototype available for the object.

any other suggestions are most welcome.

thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-set

Comment: Why are you using ie10?

Comment: actually we support IE11 but few machines are installed with IE 10. but we cant force client to switch to IE11 yet :(

Comment: @AbhijeetKale ok ...create the code without `Set` property .show your code and requirement. we are give a alternate suggestion

Comment: Are you trying to create an array that does not contain duplicate elements?

Comment: @prasad yes prasad that is a alternative but code change at this stage in my project is very costly provided the code has already passes System Testing and doing code code change will require System Test again.

Comment: @guest271314 yes I want a data structure which does not allow duplicate element. but the this is I cant change JSP/Javascript code now. I need to add something to make it work

Comment: _"but the this is I cant change JSP/Javascript code now."_ ,  _"I need to add something to make it work"_ If you cannot change the code  how can you "add something"?

Comment: @guest271314 we have a already existing JS that gets included when rendering the JSP. the actual JSP that contains code that Uses Set is tested and any changes in that JSP will raise concerns. safe way to do right now for me is to change a JS file in the framework which already has some code to support Arrays in IE5

Comment: You can still implement your own set

Comment: Not following. Either you can change the code or you cannot change the code.  If you cannot change the code the present inquiry cannot logically have an answer. If you can change the code, then there are options for implementing requirement of not allowing duplicate elements in array. How is ie5 related? Have you searched github for a `Set` polyfill?

Comment: thanks all but i think https://github.com/lukasolson/simple-js-set/blob/master/set.js here there is already a prototype for a Set this might work will keep you guys posted